# I don't understand this step in this exercise involving algebra

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In the solution of an exercise they go from $e^{2y} = x + x\cdot e^{2y}$ straight to $e^{2y} = x / (1-x)$. Could anybody explain to me how/why this is possible?

Comment: Are you sure you do not miss anything in the equation?

Comment: I missed an x, updated the question, now the equation is 100% correct, I still don't understand how to solve it though.

Comment: From the equation both sides minus $e^{2y}$ then we have $e^{2y}-xe^{2y}=x$ then we have $(1-x)e^{2y}=x$ and you get the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subtracting $xe^{2y}$ on both sides we obtain
$e^{2y}-xe^{2y}=x$
factorizing
$e^{2y}(1-x)=x$ therefore
$e^{2y}=\frac{x}{1-x}$